# JMeter File Upload with HTTP Put Method Not Working

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, http-put

The idea is to build a sampler in JMeter that will upload a file using the HTTP PUT method. I'm trying to follow the [official documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to specify the entire content body as a file with no parameter name.

- What should happen: The file gets uploaded and the server returns 201: created
- What actually happens:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sendPutData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1067)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:274)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1054)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1043)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

This seems to indicate that JMeter has a problem with filling out the body of a request. I can get rid of this error by specifying a parameter with the request, but I want the entire body to be the photo data. Here's the CURL line of what I want accomplished:

`curl -u testuser:testpass "http://localhost:8080/photo" -T photo.jpg -H "content-type:image/jpeg"`

I've tried setting the content-encoding to UTF-8 as I've seen in one post, but that changed nothing.

I'm running Java 1.7.0 on Windows 7 x64. Nothing of interest gets generated in jmeter.log, and wireshark tells me that JMeter isn't sending the request.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just adding an update. I checked out the source code and it looks like there might be a bug in 2.6. I'm confirming through the mailing list now.

Comment: Filed a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug that the nice folks at JMeter were able to fix very quickly: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52897

Using the nightly build solved my problem, and by now it has probably made it into the release.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Raw HTTP Request](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RawRequest) to accomplish this. You may specify headers in Request Data and also specify file containing PUT body for convinience.

Some details may be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/VDqXDNDCr6w/overview)

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with image uploads and found the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2115944/455363.
After making the suggested changes here I had to re-record the transaction and make my edits and I was successfully able to upload files.

Hope this helps.