# How to use HTTP PUT using JMeter which updates a file

Tags: rest, jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x, put

I have to do load test for PUT(REST service) request which uploads a file.

I'm able to consume successfully from Advanced Rest Client with the following info:

Service:

`PUT http://localhost:8080/home/cmistest/app/documentservices/rest/nodes/upload/12178`

Headers:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data, Accept: application/json
```

Response:

```
{
  "UploadContentResponse": {
    "Id": 12179,
    "ContentUrl": "http://localhost:8080/home/cmistest/app/documentservices/rest/nodes/12179/content"
  }
}
```

I'm unable to use PUT from JMeter.

I can see [JMeter File Upload with HTTP Put Method Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672706/jmeter-file-upload-with-http-put-method-not-working)
But not sure which headers needs to be set.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd start by reviewing [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) This company's site has proven quite valuable to me.

At the Test Plan level add the following Configuration Element:

```
HTTP Request Defaults
    Web Server Name:    localhost
    Port Number:        8080
    Protocol:           http
    Content Encoding:   utf8
```

Within the Thread Group, add this Configuration Element:

```
HTTP Header Manager
    Name:   Content-Type
    Value:  application/json
```

Now if you're actually creating the json data that you're passing, I'd parameterize it via a RegEx, which can then be used in the PUT request.

```
CREATE HTTP Request
    Method:     POST
    Path:       /home/cmistest/app/documentservices/rest/nodes/create/12178
    Use multipart/form-data for POST: enabled
    Body Data:
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Star Lord",
        "address": "123 Milky Way",

    }

    Regular Expression Extractor
        Name:           newWhateverId
        Apply To:       Main Sample Only
        Field to check: Body
        Reference Name: newWhateverId
        Regular Expression: \,"Id":(.+?)\,
        Template:       $1$
        Match No.:      1
        Default Value:  NONE

    Regular Expression Extractor
        Name:           newWhateverBody
        Apply To:       Main Sample Only
        Field to check: Body
        Reference Name: newWhateverBody
        Regular Expression: (?s)(^.*)
        Template:       $1$
        Match No.:      1
        Default Value:  NONE
```

Then in the PUT HTTP Request you can just pass in the values:

```
PUT HTTP Request
    Method:     PUT
    Path:       /home/cmistest/app/documentservices/rest/nodes/upload/${newWhateverId}
    Body Data:
    {
        ${newWhateverBody}          
    }
```